# TextFieldComponent is overlapped by keyboard in jetpack compose in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have five TextFieldComponent inside a Column, when you click the last two TextFieldComponent, the keyboard hides it, if you hide the keyboard and click again last TextField, works fine.

Any suggestions? I feel that for TextFieldComponent, the solutions is not similar to TextField

I tried imePadding() and all sorts of things but doesn't seem to help

Comment: Did you try adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following piece of code in your Activity file?

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(android.R.id.content)) { view, insets ->
        view.updatePadding(bottom = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom)
        insets
}
```